# Linux routes for point-to-point Ethernet network in presence of a default route

Tags: linux, ethernet, route, iproute2

**SOLUTION**: There's a typo in the IP address on my laptop Ethernet interface (see the accepted answer). The following writeup is most probably proper setup.

---

I'd like to communicate with Raspberry Pi (rpi) via point-to-point Ethernet between my laptop and the rpi.

My laptop is connected to the Internet via wireless `wlan0` interface managed by NetworkManager (DHCP). My Ethernet interface is `eth0` and I've explicitly told NetworkManager to ignore it (`nmcli dev set eth0 managed no`).

rpi apparently assigns address in the range `169.245.0.0/16` to its Ethernet interface. When I run tcpdump on my laptop Ethernet interface (`tcpdump -i eth0 -e`) I can see the rpi talking from `169.254.85.159`. I'd like to at least ping it from my laptop.

---

First I assign IP address `169.245.0.1/16` to the Ethernet interface on my laptop:

```
root@localhost ~ # ip addr add 169.245.0.1/16 dev eth0
```

---

Then I check that it has the correct address:

```
root@localhost ~ # ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f5:fc:60:62:92:f1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.157/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 1893sec preferred_lft 1893sec
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:e5:3c:f4:34:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.245.0.1/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

Then I check the route table:

```
root@localhost ~ # ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp metric 600
169.245.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.245.0.1
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.157 metric 600
```

I assume that anything to `169.245.0.0/16` will be picked up by second route entry.

---

But apparently it's picked up by default route entry:

```
root@localhost ~ # traceroute 169.254.85.159
traceroute to 169.254.85.159 (169.254.85.159), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  4.961 ms  10.669 ms  10.681 ms^C
```

Could you please explain why is the packet routed through the default route and what's the most proper way to set up such point to point network?

---

I've also tried to use the `-B` switch of ping to force the interface:

```
root@localhost ~ # ping -B eth0 169.254.85.159
```

Now in the `tcpdump` output I can see echo requests and replies from rpi but apparently it's not delivered to the `ping` because it's silent. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 169.245.0.0/16 to its Ethernet interface. When I run tcpdump on my laptop Ethernet interface (tcpdump -i eth0 -e) I can see the rpi talking from 169.254.85.159

You seem to have a typo.  Your RPI is 169.**254**.85.159.  And you assigned 169.**245**.0.0/16 to your other computer.  254!=245.

Though if your RPi is really getting a APIPA address in the 169.254/16 range it makes me wonder if you even have good connectivity.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing. Thank you! Now it works. Should I delete the question?

Comment: You don't have to delete it.